# Callable not defined for django.db.models field default

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am using PyCharm 4.5.2, Django 1.8.2.

If I define a class as:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, unique=True, default=make_slug)

    def make_slug(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name[0]
```

The IDE highlights `default=make_slug` with `make_slug` being undefined. The interpretter agrees and when the development server tries to refresh it exits with status `1` and the error `NameError: name 'make_slug' is not defined.`

Because it's just the name of a callable, I can't pass arguments. So if I define the function outside the class (to move into a higher scope and be defined) I can't use the class properties. I have read some suggestions that use lambdas but from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default) that is wrong:

> Note that lambdas cannot be used for field options like default
>   because they cannot be serialized by migrations. See that
>   documentation for other caveats.

What is the proper way to define a callable for default values in a model.

Comment: try moving the definition of `make_slug` before the attributes, i.e. just above `first_name = ...`

Comment: @Pynchia Tried that and another problem creeps up. The `makemigrations` and `migrate` tasks work, but when I go to add a user in the admin panel, I get a `TypeError`: `make_slug() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. Removing the `self` argument from the method negates the class properties, and gives another `must accept one argument, usually self` warning.

Comment: alright. You got an answer below. BTW: why are you redefining the User class? Consider using a one-to-one relationship, it makes life [easier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) (at least to me)

Comment: @Pynchia Simple answer: ignorance. For moment I thought that it probably had a built in users management system, but since I am just starting with Django I built the class for a simple "can I make this work" test. Thank you again, for the link, I'll be reading it tomorrow and probably refactoring because it's likely the better answer.

Comment: Kudos to your honesty. I ain't a Django master myself. Trying things out is the best approach for learning and I think you are on the right track. Have fun! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use this method to set your default value, rather than override the save method of the model and use it there. For example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=256, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1)

    def make_slug(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name[0]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = self.make_slug()
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This works, however, the documentation indicates I should be able to use callable in this way. I hope to get an answer that addresses that, but if I don't in a few days I will simply accept this. Thank you, I didn't know about `uuid`.

Comment: it also doesn't work if you just added the slug field to an existing model. The migration will ask for a one time value.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error

`NameError: name 'make_slug' is not defined.`

because you refer to `make_slug` before you defined it. If you moved the `make_slug` function above the `slug` field, then you wouldn't get that error.

However, it isn't possible to pass *any* arguments to the callable that you use as the default, so that won't work either. You can't get around that restriction by using a model method as you are trying.

If you need access to the model instance to calculate the default, then setting the value in the `save()` method as ruddra suggests is a good idea. Note that you might want to check whether or not the model has a primary key, so that you only create the slug when you first create the instance.